# Forward debian LAN to another router without nat

Tags: debian, firewall, nat

Is it possible to create network forwarding through debian without using nat?
I have the following network structure.

```
ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- Internet - wan - [Router with nat] --- lan (10.1.1.1/24 ---- eth1 (10.1.1.2/24) [Debian ] eth0--- (192.168.1.1/24)----Tplink Router (192.168.1.2/24)
```

I would like to pass the entire 192.168.0.x network so that I can nat on the first router, not on debian.
I enabled packet routing:

```
echo 1> / proc / sys / net / ipv4 / ip_forward
```

I can ping the ip 10.1.1.2 that is in the debian eth1, but not the 10.1.1.1 of my main router.

Comment: This is really a question for https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can forward (route), or you can bridge. Details depend on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems; which it is you can find out running `tcpdump` on the Debian router's 10.1.1.2 interface:

- Either the Debian router does not let the packets through (because the firewall configuration may not allow it)
- or the Internet router receives the packets but does not reply (correctly).

In order for the Internet router to respond correctly you have to configure a static route there with `10.1.1.2` as gateway for `192.168.1.0/24`.

Comment: How could I create a route? Saying that the 192.168.1.x / 24 network will have gw 10.1.1.2?
Can you please exemplify?

Comment: @banana That probably has to be done in the router's web interface. In a Linux root shell you would do this: `ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.1.1.2`. That is effective until the next reboot only.